# How to test or style the order success page?

Tags: checkout, development

If I reload the `checkout/onepage/success` page, I am directed to the cart.

So, when debugging or styling the order success page, I always have to make a new order.

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: This question created varied answers which are all full of "win". Anyone visiting here should peruse all the answers.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can **temporarily** hack the core while you are developing:

In `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php` edit `successAction()`.

Comment out the line `$session->clear();`. Now you can make one order and refresh the page as often as you like.

If you do not even want to make an order on each browser, for example when doing cross-browser testing, you also can just initialize the session every time.

Pick an order id and a quote id from the table `sales_flat_order` (fields: `entity_id` and `quote_id`). For example via:

```
SELECT entity_id as order_id, quote_id 
  FROM sales_flat_order ORDER BY entity_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then change the beginning of the function as follows:

```
$session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();

$session->setLastSuccessQuoteId(INSERT_QUOTE_ID);
$session->setLastQuoteId(INSERT_QUOTE_ID);
$session->setLastOrderId(INSERT_ORDER_ID);
```

and replace`INSERT_....` with the IDs.

Now you can always call `checkout/onepage/success`

While you are at it, you might want to test the `failureAction()` as well, in

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

The modified action would look like this

```
public function failureAction()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();

        $session->setLastSuccessQuoteId(INSERT_QUOTE_ID);
        $session->setLastQuoteId(INSERT_QUOTE_ID);
        $session->setLastOrderId(INSERT_ORDER_ID);

        $lastQuoteId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastQuoteId();
        $lastOrderId = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();

        if (!$lastQuoteId || !$lastOrderId) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Now you can always call `checkout/onepage/failure`

Comment: Fixes this your problem? Please mark it as solution.

Comment: I've tested both Jisse Reitsma's Yireo Checkout Tester and this method. While the module is the easiest way, I found it to be not 100% compatible with our theme and payment module, resulting in a different styling than the original succes page. While requiring to modify the core this method however worked like a charm. Note: the answer is missing the file you need to edit, which is /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

Comment: For people that would like to do the same in M2 you can comment lines 19 to 22 in `\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success.php`

Answer (score 26):

You need to modify the successAction() in

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

Modified action would like this

```
public function successAction()
    {
        /*
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
        if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
        $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
        $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
        if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $session->clear();
        */
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Comment: But then `$lastOrderId` is not defined which would leat to a notice and to could lead to side effects in the template.

Comment: I've had success just by commenting out the $session->clear(); The only thing I lose is any notices/messages added such as TBT/Rewards Notices/Messages added via observer. Leaving the code in a override module, which is .gitignored so never deployed.

Answer (score 19):

Hope I'm not too self-promoting, but I created a free extension that can be quickly installed in Magento, and allows you to preview the order success-page for any order - simply by accessing an URL:
http://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/checkout-tester

Answer (score 5):

I think it's better to just comment $session->clear(); and add products manually, that worked for me but commenting the whole action gave me syntax errors.

Answer (score 5):

**For Magento 2:**

If you want to style or customize in success page after order success page redirects to cart page.

Now solution is here:

Go To `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage`
 open `Success.php` File.

In this file, you see Below Code

```
 if (!$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator')->isValid()) {
     return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
 }
```

Just comment on this code and your problem is solved. After comment this you don't redirect to cart page.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of sending out emails from local/development copy you can dump the content of the email to a file and then just see locally, which in my opinion will be really handy. Here's how that can be acheived. First all the emails are sent from

```
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
```

Find that, and add the following lines.

```
    $this->setUseAbsoluteLinks(true);
    $text = $this->getProcessedTemplate($variables, true);

    if($this->isPlain()) {
        $mail->setBodyText($text);
    } else {
        $mail->setBodyHTML($text);
    }
    // Added Code //
    $filePath = Mage::getBaseDir() .  DS . 'email.html';
    Mage::log($filePath);
    file_put_contents($filePath, $text);
    // Added Code Ends //

    $mail->setSubject('=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->getProcessedTemplateSubject($variables)) . '?=');
    $mail->setFrom($this->getSenderEmail(), $this->getSenderName());
```

After this after you create any order an email.html will be created in the Magento document root and you can open that in browser to see the output.

Next, to send/re-send any order emails you can just log in admin and for each order there is Send Email button which will trigger this script and you can see the newly changed template written in the same file. I think this is one of the best way to see order or any other emails.

Please note to remove the added code when you are done.

Answer (score 2):

#### Magento 2

As another answer notes, you can comment out the redirect in `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success::execute` and force the checkout success page to load. But when the block, `Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success`, loads no order data will be present because `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::getLastRealOrder` won't return an order. A better option would be an after interceptor on the controller class's execute method, where you can set a value for `lastRealOrderId` in the checkout session.

This approach also provides an opportunity to dispatch the `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event with your desired order. The event will trigger the observers `Magento\GoogleAdwords\Observer\SetConversionValueObserver` and `Magento\GoogleAnalytics\Observer\SetGoogleAnalyticsOnOrderSuccessPageViewObserver` with your test data.

The following is a fairly basic module creating the interceptor described above and allows setting the order by appending an `order` query parameter with the desired increment id to the success page URL. It currently won't work the multi shipping success route. It can be downloaded on GitHub: https://github.com/pmclain/magento2-successtest

> app/code/Pmclain/SuccessTest/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success">
    <plugin name="pmclain_successtest_checkout_controller_onepage_success"
            type="Pmclain\SuccessTest\Plugin\Success"
            sortOrder="10" />
  </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pmclain/SuccessTest/Plugin/Success.php

```
<?php
namespace Pmclain\SuccessTest\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Success
{
  /** @var ManagerInterface */
  protected $_eventManager;

  /** @var PageFactory */
  protected $_resultPageFactory;

  /** @var ScopeConfigInterface */
  protected $_scopeConfig;

  /** @var OrderFactory */
  protected $_orderFactory;

  /** @var Order */
  protected $_order;

  /** @var Session */
  protected $_checkoutSession;

  /**
   * Success constructor.
   * @param ManagerInterface $eventManager
   * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
   * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
   * @param OrderFactory $orderFactory
   * @param Session $session
   */
  public function __construct(
    ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    OrderFactory $orderFactory,
    Session $session
  ) {
    $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    $this->_checkoutSession = $session;
  }

  /**
   * @param \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success $subject
   * @param $result
   * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
   */
  public function afterExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success $subject, $result)
  {
    if (!$this->_isEnabled()) {
      return $result;
    }

    $order = $this->_getTestOrder($subject->getRequest()->getParam('order'));

    if (!$order->getId()) {
      return $result;
    }

    $this->_checkoutSession->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());

    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
      'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
      ['order_ids' => [$order->getId()]]
    );

    return $resultPage;
  }

  /**
   * @return bool
   */
  protected function _isEnabled()
  {
    if ($this->_scopeConfig->getValue('dev/debug/success_test', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * @param $incrementId string|bool
   * @return Order
   */
  protected function _getTestOrder($incrementId)
  {
    /** @var Order $order */
    $order = $this->_orderFactory->create();

    $order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);

    return $order;
  }
}
```

> app/code/Pmclain/SuccessTest/etc/adminhtml/system.xml
>   Below adds admin panel options to enable/disable the interceptor.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
  <system>
    <section id="dev">
      <group id="debug">
        <field id="success_test" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
          <label>Enable Checkout Success Page Testing</label>
          <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
        </field>
      </group>
    </section>
  </system>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pmclain/SuccessTest/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
  <default>
    <dev>
      <debug>
        <success_test>0</success_test>
      </debug>
    </dev>
  </default>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pmclain/SuccessTest/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Pmclain_SuccessTest" setup_version="0.0.1">
    <sequence>
      <module name="Magento_Backend" />
      <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
    </sequence>
  </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Pmclain/SuccessTest/resgistration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
  \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
  'Pmclain_SuccessTest',
  __DIR__
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update code:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

Update function:

```
public function successAction()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    $lastQuoteId = $session->getLastQuoteId();
    $lastOrderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
    $lastRecurringProfiles = $session->getLastRecurringProfileIds();
    if (!$lastQuoteId || (!$lastOrderId && empty($lastRecurringProfiles))) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    }

    //$session->clear();

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Just comment:

```
//$session->clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Magento 2

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage # vi Success.php +26`

comment out:

```
//        $session->clearQuote();
```