# Display Message On Thank You Page If Shipping Method Is Equal To

Tags: checkout, shipping, event-observer

We have added an in-store pick up shipping method to our magento stores. We would like to display travel instructions to the store on the thank you page.

Any ideas on how I can go about displaying this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At your `checkout/success.phtml` you can do something like this:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
if ($order->getShippingMethod() == 'your_shipping_method_code') {
    // display travel instructions
}
```

Comment: Should this be for shipping method, not for payment method?

Comment: oh, sorry. misread. 1 sec.

Comment: Wouldn't `getLastOrderId` produce inaccurate results on busy stores? Can't you just grab the quote/order singleton?

Comment: Never heard of it (doesn't mean that you are wrong). Magento is using `getLastOrderId` by themselves in `Mage_Checkout_Block_Success`.

Comment: @sonassi: Funny thing is that neither `getLastOrderId` nor `quote/order` singleton are not working at checkout success page. Please see my updated answer for a solution.

Comment: and thanks to @Alex for his solution http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/836/93