# Inserting data into database

Tags: magento-enterprise, checkout, database, onepage-checkout

I use this code added into `success.phtml` when ever I run this code the webpage crashes. The success page just never loads and stays white. I'm sure its a simple mistake that I am making but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. So I figured i'd give it a shot on here.

This code is near the beginning of the file and works fine

```
$grayson_order_id = $this->getOrderId();
$order2 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($grayson_order_id);
$custname = $order2->getBillingAddress()->getName();
```

This code however does not work.

```
<?php
echo "a";
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
echo "b";
echo "<br />";
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
echo "c";
echo "<br />";
$order->load($lastOrderId);
echo "c";
echo "<br />";
$totalAmount = $order->getData('base_grand_total');
echo "d";
echo "<br />";
echo "total amount ". $totalAmount;
echo "<br />";
$sellerId = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('smashingmagazine_affiliate_source');
echo "e";
echo "<br />";
echo "aff id ". $sellerId;
echo "<br />";
$w = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
echo "f";
echo "<br />";
$result = $w->query('INSERT INTO grayson_custom (refer, time, amount, name, order_id) VALUES ('$sellerId', 'date('Y-m-d H:i:s')','$totalAmount','$custname','$this->getOrderId()')');
echo "g";
echo "<br />";

?>
```

I don't think it matters much but I am using Magento Enterprise Edition 1.13

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: How to test the order page: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/835/how-to-test-or-style-the-order-success-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is on this line:

`$result = $w->query('INSERT INTO grayson_custom (refer, time, amount, name, order_id) VALUES ('$sellerId', 'date('Y-m-d H:i:s')','$totalAmount','$custname','$this->getOrderId()')');`

Can be fixed by changing to:

`$result = $w->query('INSERT INTO grayson_custom (refer, time, amount, name, order_id) VALUES ('.$sellerId.', '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').','.$totalAmount.','.$custname.','.$this->getOrderId().')');`

What ever you are trying to do **STOP**, this is not how you should be developing on Magento, this sort of action should be handled with a custom module and a making use of [Magento Observer Event triggers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method), `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` if possible.

Also I think you might have a SQL injection on the above line, because you get the Cookie `smashingmagazine_affiliate_source`, if the user maliciously malforms the cookie it could potentially cause a security breach!

http://magentotherightway.com/ | http://www.phptherightway.com/ | *Hire a developer*

Comment: I am aware of the SQL injection security issue but I haven't gotten that far yet. This code used to be ran on the onepage checkout success event but I moved it directly into `success.phtml` when debugging. Thanks for all your help! And the links!

Comment: Ah ok, you did give a *wtf* moment. Hope this fixes your issue. I would look at creating a resource model so you can use the Magento ORM http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/ instead of pure SQL.

Comment: I get the magento error page and it says the error message is hidden by default for security reasons. How can i view the error? i looked in the log files and didn't find anything

Comment: As input mentioned, this approach would open up you to exploitation.  I'd follow the tutorial and code closer your following: https://github.com/josephmcdermott/SmashingMagazine-MagentoAffiliateTracking