# Is there a Way to test Checkout Templates?

Tags: checkout, template, frontend, review, testing

I've got the problem that we use paypal express on our Page and the Review Page (Url like http://mysite.dev/paypal/express/review) looks wrong and is not usable by the customer.

Now i want to optimize this site so that it looks good.
But i got the problem that i can't step through the checkout process every time i do some  changes.

Isn't there a proper way to test templates in the Checkout?

Comment: See also: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180239/81

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. There is a great free extension for this purpose, [Yireo Checkout Tester](https://github.com/yireo/Yireo_CheckoutTester) but it only supports testing of the success page (as of current version 0.1.7).

But if you take this as an example you can probably write your own test controller that loads the paypal express review page in the same way.