# Magento Success page, only half or less being reported in Google Analytics

Tags: checkout, google-analytics

Since the past month Google Analytic are been reporting the incorrect amount of views going to the Magento Success page for 2 days ago it said I had 11 people hit the success page but I had 22 orders with emails, emails only being sent out if the user goes to the success page.

No changes have been made to the magento checkout system up to 3 weeks before the problem started happening, Is there any reason this could be happening or anything I should be looking at to get the correct results showing again.

Checkout Progress does as following:

Cart -> Enter Billing Details -> Enter Shipping Details -> Select Shipping Method -> Select payment method -> Redirected to payment provider website -> Redirect back on payment to Success page

The site uses Universal analytics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **many** things that can interrupt the Google Analytics reporting. In my experience most of the time this is due to a Javascript error / exception in the code prior to the GA async push event.

Other times there is an exception **in the PHP code** which is happening somewhere on the page that is not visible. I have seen sites where this happens in the `before_body_end` block, the error doesn't display, and the page looks as if it loads normally.

The best way to tell if this is happening is to view generated source and see if both the `</body>` and `</html>` tags are present.

If you need help working on the Success page there is a quick workaround that will prevent you from having to re-place orders every iteration:

[How to test or style the order success page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/835/how-to-test-or-style-the-order-success-page)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the link, reading from your answer this sounds more of an issue if it wasn't getting tracked at all were as my problem is it seems to be 50/50 if it gets tracked.

Comment: I used to think the same thing until I did closer inspection. 50/50 is an awfully suspicious number. It sounds a lot like some functionality around guest vs registered; paypal vs gateway; affiliate vs ppc vs organic; dropship orders vs in house fulfilled. Are there js errors on the page? Dig into some of the custom code on the page and ensure there is no custom functionality firing off based on the above.

Comment: I've managed to go through and fix the errors. I've left it a bit to make sure and while it was fine over the weekend the problem returned

Comment: Keep track of it and apart from 1 order now and then everything gone to normal. Can't fully explain why but this feedback was the last thing I did on the site